# How to embed javascript into content region

Tags: javascript

I am trying to embed javascript into the content page of my page. I decided to use php filter and the following is my code:

```
<?php
$scripty = "http://blah.com/plugins/embedvanilla/remote.js";
drupal_add_js($scripty, array(
'type' => 'external',
'scope' => 'content',
'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
'every_page' => FALSE,
'weight' => -1,
)
);
?>
```

The script shows on this page if scope is not set (which means it defaults to header).

How can I get it to display in the content region?

Answer (score 1):

Never use php filter, it's one of the worst inventions in Drupal.

You can create a region in your info theme.  Then, use the preprocess hook like that:

```
function hook_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  // Region names of (header|footer) collide with drupal_add_js()'s
  // (header|footer) labels.
  $scope_theme = 'your_region';
  if (!empty($scope_theme) && $scope_theme != 'footer' && $scope_theme != 'header'
    && $vars['region'] == $scope_theme) {

    // Inject javascript into page.
    $javascript = drupal_get_js($vars['region']);
    $vars['content'] = $javascript . $vars['content'];
  }

}
```

And finally, fire your drupal_add_js using the region you defined wherever you prefer... But never in php filter

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has several ways to include javascript, but the most common is to define the script file in a module or theme .info file. Drupal will handle the inclusion and aggregation of your script file.

For more information on your options, have a look at the [Developers Guide](http://drupal.org/node/121997).

Comment: `drupal_add_js()` is actually far and away the most common method to include javascript (there are 100 calls in core modules and themes alone). That method gives you better control of scope/group/weight as well; according to the OP's requirements in the question, he would also need to implement `hook_js_alter()` to control the scope/group/weight if he used the .info include method. Seems a bit redundant when he's already got the correct code, he's just invoking it in the wrong place :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a scope other than `header` & `footer` is not supported with Drupal core's themes and most contrib themes. Using any scope is supported in all themes if you're using [AdvAgg](https://drupal.org/project/advagg) though. After installing AdvAgg you will need to add this to you're settings.php file to enable JS outside of normal scopes.

```
// Allow JavaScript insertion into any scope even if theme does not support it.
$conf['advagg_scripts_scope_anywhere'] = TRUE;
```

This is one of the hidden settings inside AdvAgg. You can read about the hidden settings inside of the [AdvAgg readme](http://drupalcode.org/project/advagg.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/README.txt).

Answer (score -1):

If you're using php filter on your page, couldn't you just add the script tag into the node body?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blah.com/plugins/embedvanilla/remote.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have tried doing this put it's not being saved to the node body. after saving, when i go back to edit the page there's nothing :(

Comment: If the input format of the node is [PHP Code](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/php), you should be able to embed that script tag.